# Can every recursive function be rewritten using tail calls?

Tags: haskell, clojure, functional-programming, lisp, scheme

Can every recursive function be rewritten using tail calls? If not, what are examples of recursive functions for which this can't be done?

Comment: tl;dr If you're willing to add an extra parameter explicitly representing the calling context, then yes.

Comment: ... but of course that frequently means more than O(1) auxiliary space cost.

Comment: The calling context has to be represented somehow, somewhere, just as it is before the transformation. There's also a danger that transformation into tail-recursive form obscures opportunities for parallelism.